# Chapter 2 Section 17 Problem 15 - Mary L Boas.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

> For what $z$ is the series $\sum\;z^{\ln n}\; $absolutely convergent?

$$\sum z^{\ln n} = \sum e^{(\ln n)(\ln z)} = \sum n^{\ln z}$$

According to $p$ series test, the series converges when $p>1$, so
$$\ln z < -1\\z<e^{-1}\\z<1/e$$

Is this the correct way to solve it and how to show $\vert z\vert<1/e$?

Comment: Your posts will look nicer and be easier to read if you write `\ln` instead of `ln`.  Similarly for $\sin$ and many other common functions.

Comment: Just start with $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$, and you'll find $\left|z^{\ln{n}}\right|= |z|^{\ln n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z$ is suppose to be a complex number then $\ln z <-1$ does not make sense.

$z^{\ln n}$ is not single valued but this doesn't matter as long as absolute convegrence is concerned.

$|z^{\ln n}|=|z|^{\ln n}=n^{\ln |z|}$ and $\sum n^{r}$ is convergent iff $r <-1$. Hence the given series is absolutely convergent iff $\ln |z| <-1$ or $|z|<\frac 1 e$.